# Abusing Enchant Magic Item

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

Is there anything that prevents a character from using the free resize-function of the Enchant Magic Item ritual to store  an infinite amount of magic items in his backpack by making them exceptionally small?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As written](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=9), that only seems to work for magic armor (emphasis mine):

> You can also use this ritual to resize **magic armor**

So while it could be abused, it's not as bad as it looks.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's not as bad as I thought it was! In fact, it's actually a pretty neat idea!

Comment: Plus I'd rule that the armour must be appropriate to the size, so how many Tiny creatures wear Plate   :-)

Comment: @SteveC I don't know about Tiny creatures, but in fact most Fine creatures wear plate armor (it just happens to be permanently bonded to their bodies).

Answer (score 5):

I doubt it for the following reason.

Bags of holding and handy haversacks are incredibly common in the D&D 4e world. They allow you to hold a very large amount of items and it only weigh a pound.

If you can abstract something one way why not abstract it another way.

Both of these methods are to prevent unnecessary book keeping.

However, I have a feeling that the method suggested in this question could be an interesting opportunity for the DM.

> Player: "I'd like to resize my miniscule full blade"
>
> DM: "Roll to see if you can find it"
>
> Player: "Uh Oh. I rolled a 1"
>
> DM: "You've managed to lose every single item in your backpack that was sized below tiny"

Comment: Also, anything the player can abuse, the DM can abuse :)